# Execute commands in shell scripts in sequence

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I want to execute set of commands in shell scripting one after another. But the catch is the first command starts a process and second and third command are the inputs to the process started by the first command.

```
 Example :
   command_1 = myapp
   command_2 = input_1
   command_3 = input_2
```

### it should be executed like :

```
>>myapp
     >>input_1
       output_1
     >>input_2
       output_2
```

After execution of all commands, I want to store the output_1 & output_2 also.

Comment: On UNIX you can pipe output from one command as input to the next using the symbol `|`. Like `ls -l | wc -l`. Maybe a similar function is available in powershell.

Comment: 1 - Make sure to update your tags to correctly indicate whether you are using PowerShell or Linux shell. 2 - Update your post to include an example of what you have so far. If there is sensitive information, then create a minimal example.

Comment: How are the inputs "connected" to the first process? It's unclear how those processes are related (and why timing matters)

Comment: It's really not clear what you mean. Perhaps `(command2 | tee output_1; command3 | tee output_2 ) | myapp` to run `command2` and `command3` and provide their standard output as standard input to `myapp`. Or `myapp "$(command2 | tee output_1)" "$(command3 | tee output_2)" to run `myapp` with the output of `command2` and `command3` as command-line parameters. Both of these problems are well-covered duplicates; going forward, please search before asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `xargs` tool to accomplish this (xargs builds and executes command lines from standard input).

`ls -1 *README* | xargs -i grep -oP "https://\S+" {} | xargs -i echo "found link {}"`

Read the man page for `xargs` for details.

Alternatively, for more complex processing, you can pipe the output into variables and
do for-loops:

```
files=$(ls -1 *README*)
for file in $files; do
  links=$(grep -oP "https://\S+" $file)
done

for link in $links; do
  echo "found link $link"
done
```